# Condition of the matrix

Tags: matrices

**I have a problem is** find the condition $$K_\infty (B_n)$$
where
$$ B_n =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1      & -1      & -1      & \cdots & -1 \\
        0      &  1      & -1      & \cdots & -1 \\
        \vdots &  \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots &  \vdots\\
        0      &  0      &  0      & 0      &  1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

**My solution is**
$$B_n^{-1} =
       \begin{bmatrix}
        1      & 2^0     & 2^1     & \cdots & 2^{n-2}\\
        0      &  1      & 2^0     & \cdots & 2^{n-3} \\
        \vdots &  \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots &  \vdots\\
        0      &  0      &  0      & 1      & 2^0\\
        0      &  0      &  0      & 0      &  1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$K_∞ = ||B_n||_\infty ||B_n^{-1}||_\infty = n 2^{n-1}$$

**My TA solution is**
$$
||x||_\infty = 1=> 
\begin{cases} 
M = \max||B_n  x||_\infty = \max(|\text{row sum}|) = n\\ 
m = \min||B_n  x||_\infty = \min(|\text{row sum}|) = 1 
\end{cases}
\implies K_\infty = \frac{M}{m} = n
$$

**Why 2 methods giving 2 differences results?**

Comment: Please use LaTeX, it is nearly impossible to read your question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks. First time knowing there are LaTex.

Comment: Your solution seems to be right. The second method is valid only for symmetric matrices and Euclidian norm. What is TA, besides?

Comment: TA is Teaching Assistant